# ORACLE convert datetime without milliseconds

Tags: sql, oracle, datetime

Hi I have this column: DATETIME_UTC as timestamp(9):

```
2/3/2019 1:27:00.000000 AM
```

How I can convert this column in select statement as:

```
2/3/2019 1:27:00 AM
```

Just need to delete milliseconds. Just need to convert and keep it as date

Regards

Comment: **cast( ..... as date)**

Answer (score 0):

My full test script:

```
set linesize 32000
set pagesize 1000
set head on
set echo on
set termout on
set trimspool on

spool test2.log

-- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68840203/oracle-convert-datetime-without-milliseconds

-- desired format 2/3/2019 1:27:00 AM

alter session set nls_date_format='MM/DD/YYYY HH12:MI:SS AM';

drop table test;

create table test (datetime_utc timestamp(9));

insert into test values (to_timestamp('02/03/2019 01:27:00.000000 AM','MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI:SS.FF6 AM'));
commit;

select datetime_utc from test;

-- general approach to change dates and times
-- convert to string and back

select to_date(to_char(datetime_utc,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'),'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') from test;

-- suggested in comments - simpler way to just truncate milliseconds

select cast(datetime_utc as date) from test;

spool off
```

Last part of the output:

```
SQL> select datetime_utc from test;

DATETIME_UTC
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
03-FEB-19 01.27.00.000000000 AM

SQL> 
SQL> -- general approach to change dates and times
SQL> -- convert to string and back
SQL> 
SQL> select to_date(to_char(datetime_utc,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'),'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') from test;

TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(DATETI
----------------------
02/03/2019 01:27:00 AM

SQL> 
SQL> -- suggested in comments - simpler way to just truncate milliseconds
SQL> 
SQL> select cast(datetime_utc as date) from test;

CAST(DATETIME_UTCASDAT
----------------------
02/03/2019 01:27:00 AM
```

Cast is the more efficient solution for this question but converting to a string and back to date can solve a number of date and time problems so it is a more general solution.

Bobby

Comment: Or simply `cast(datetime as date)`

Answer (score 0):

You are showing the same time twice. `2/3/2019 1:27:00.000000 AM` is exactly the same timestamp as `2/3/2019 1:27:00 AM`. It's only another way of displaying it. `February 3, 2019 01:27` is yet another, and there are many other ways to display it.

So it seems you don't want to delete anything here, but merely display the timestamp differently. This is usually done in your app or website, so the timestamp gets displayed according to the user's operating system settings. (I, for instance, would see this probably as 03.02.2019 01:27, as my Windows has German settings).

But you can also ask Oracle to convert the timestamp into a string with the desired format. This is done with `TO_CHAR`. E.g.

```
select to_char(ts, 'mm/dd/yyyy hh:mi:ss am') from mytable;
```

This can be used for instance when you want to write the result into a file and you need a fixed timestamp format for this.

And if this is about your SQL tool (e.g. SQL Developer or Toad), you can probably set a default there, how to display dates and timestamps.